# Operation ("read" on "Journal Item" (account.move.line)) was rejected because of the following rules

Tags: odoo-13

The requested operation ("read" on "Journal Item" (account.move.line)) was rejected because of the following rules:

- Purchase User Account Move Line

(Records: BNK1/2020/0089 (BILL/2020/0019) Vendor Payment: BILL/2020/0019 (id=795), User: Administrator (id=2))

That error occur when i click to the created journal entries odoo

Comment: Make Sure your user have the at least 'billing' access to the accounting app.kindly confirm.

Comment: i cant edit the billing in accounting in my user setting and even i edit and save but still advisor

Answer (score -1):

Due to security restrictions, you are not allowed to access '**Journal Item**' (account.move.line) records.